# ampersand on hyperlink in alias

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, alias

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't get it to work:

1. when i type

   ```
   w3m https://www.google.com/search?q=whatever&oq=whatever&aqs=chrome..69i57.1259j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
   ```

I get exactly the results I want

2. but when I try to add an alias as in

   ```
   alias whatever='https://www.google.com/search?q=whatever&oq=whatever&aqs=chrome..69i57.1259j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
   ```

I get an error related to the presence of the ampersand

3. I also tried to substitute the ampersand by %23 but that didn't work either

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: remove the single quote before `alias`

Comment: @karakfa sorry that was a typo in my question. I've fixed it now to what I actually have on my .zshrc

Comment: I doubt that you're getting exactly what you expect, because the unquoted `&` in the first command will be interpreted by `bash` so the url will be shorter.

Comment: @liborm if i substitute the command by something that doesn't have a & I still get an error. Here is the content for my .zshrc:

    alias whatever='w3n https://www.google.com/search?q=whatever' 

and I get 

    zsh: no matches found: https://www.google.com/search?q=whatever

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution was to add a function:

```
function w3g { w3m https://www.google.com/search\?q\="$1" ;}
```

then

```
w3g whatever
```

or

```
w3g "blah blah blah"
```

Comment: In bash would have worked with alias too. It's obviously a zsh issue.